# Save Bitmap to SD Card

Tags: android, bitmap, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I have a Bitmap image which I have to store in a folder in the SD Card, my code is shown below. It creates the folder and file as expected, but the image is not stored into the file, it remains an empty file... Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
Bitmap merged = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDragLayer.getChildAt(0).getWidth(), mDragLayer.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(merged);

// save to folder in sd card
try {
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "folder");
    if(!imagesFolder.exists())
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();
    int imageNum;
    if(imagesFolder.list()==null)
        imageNum = 1;
    else
        imageNum = imagesFolder.list().length + 1;

    String fileName = "file_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
    File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
    while(output.exists()){
        imageNum++;
        fileName = "file_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
        output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
    }

    OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(output);
    merged.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First add permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Then write down in Java File as below.

```
    String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File mFolder = new File(extr + "/MyApp");

            if (!mFolder.exists()) {
                mFolder.mkdir();
            }

            String strF = mFolder.getAbsolutePath();
            File mSubFolder = new File(strF + "/MyApp-SubFolder");

            if (!mSubFolder.exists()) {
                mSubFolder.mkdir();
            }

            String s = "myfile.png";

            f = new File(mSubFolder.getAbsolutePath(),s);
```

**UPDATED**

```
           String strMyImagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
             FileOutputStream fos = null;
             try {
                 fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,70, fos);

                 fos.flush();
                 fos.close();
              //   MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "Screen", "screen");
             }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (Exception e) {

                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

Comment: And where do I put the actual Bitmap?

Answer (score 7):

you just need a bitmap

and you have to pass a path to store the image

```
Bitmap b = pagesView.getDrawingCache();
b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/NameOfFile.jpg"));
```

and you have to add permission in Manifest file..

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 7):

Don't make it difficult with complex code its really very simple please Try below code.

Create first dir in your sd card :

```
public static String strpath =  android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
public static String dirName = "DIR_NAME";

File makeDirectory = new File(strpath+"/"+dirName);
makeDirectory.mkdir();
```

Then you should make two String Var like below :

```
String filename =  "yourImageName".jpg";
String dirpath =strpath + "/"+dirName + "/";
```

Make File Variable :

```
File storagePath =  new File(dirpath);
File myImage = new File(storagePath, filename);
outStream = new FileOutputStream(myImage);  
outStream.write(data);
outStream.close();
```

Hope this may helpful to you.